# Texas Instrument SPDT TS5A22362DGSR not swtiching properly

Tags: switches, routing, analog-switch, spdt, signal-routing

I have bought a couple TS5A22362DGSR from TI and it's not switching properly, I'm trying to switch between a record player and a laptop. As shown above, I want the signal from a record player, after a RIAA preamp, and a laptop. So, left and right from RIAA are connected to pins 4 and 8 respectively while left and right from the cellphone are connected to pins 2 and 10 respectively. When I switch pins 5 and 7 to +4.8VDC the both normally open signals are fowarded to their corresponding COM's at full capacity, but also a small part of the pair of signals comming from the normally closed pins, the reciprocal also happens. I also tried to connect a 47K resistor in parallel with each signal but didn't solve the problem (image 2). Any hint on how to solve this problem?
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a22362.pdf?ts=1623947151319&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DTS5A22362DGSR
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is what is shown in the datasheet:

[image: Datasheet]

Study how the pins are wired here, and do the same in your design.

Comment: This drawing is wrong, I didn't do it, the switch is switching the control pins either to GND or to +4.8VDC, same as the 1st image.

Comment: Just edited the image.

Comment: That's what I did, and it's working partially, but as I stated, a small part of the pair of NC signals or NO are being fowared when they were not supposed to be.